# Sliding DIV disabling the controls inside the updatepanel in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I am using the code from here: http://jsfiddle.net/dJS4g/

When trying it in IE 10, everything is working fine. But in Chrome all of the content of the update panel inside "contact" div are disabled and unclickable. Here is my code.

```
<div id="contact">
      <asp:Panel CssClass="login_popup" ID="PopupMenu" runat="server" BorderColor="Maroon" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="4" Width="345px">
      <br /><br /><br />
      <div class="login_p">Log In To Wrangle</div><p></p>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>

<table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style4" style="text-align: right"><asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Username/Email:"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right" colspan="2"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Maroon" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="2px" Font-Names="Segoe UI Light" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" Width="185px"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right;vertical-align:top" class="auto-style4">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Password:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right" colspan="2">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Maroon" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="2px" Font-Names="Segoe UI Light" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" TextMode="Password" Width="185px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" CssClass="help_text" Font-Size="Small" Font-Underline="True">Forgot Password?</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style4">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" CssClass="help_text" Font-Size="Small" Text="Keep Me Logged In" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: left" class="auto-style3">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right"><div style="float:left; height:32px; width:32px">
                            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel2">
                                <ProgressTemplate><img alt="Working..." class="auto-style5" src="Images/ajaxloader.gif" width="32px" height="32px" /></ProgressTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdateProgress>
                            </div>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" BackColor="#FFCC66" BorderColor="Maroon" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="2px" CssClass="button" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Maroon" Text="Log In" OnClick="Button10_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLogError" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="Red" Text="E-Mail/Username or Password is Invalid" Visible="False" CssClass="errorLabel"></asp:Label>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: left">
                            <br />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>


           </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:Button ID="Button11" runat="server" BackColor="#FFCC66" BorderColor="Maroon" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="2px" CssClass="button" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Maroon" Text="Close" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" BackColor="#3B5999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" CssClass="button" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" Height="22px" Text="f | Log In" Width="62px" style="float:right" />
      </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

The two button outside the UpdatePanel are clickable but not the content inside it. What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you add any code-behind to this? Bindings, etc. A little more code would be helpful. Plus, the "content that freezed" would be good to see too :D

Comment: @MightyLampshade it contains some server side controls in a HTML table. The code is working fine in IE.

Comment: @mdesdev can you write in your answer where I should apply it?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva to be able to tell you that you must post a little more code, best update the Fiddle...or apply higher `z-index` to everything inside `<ContentTemplate>` or simply just on the main div, form or whatever inside `<ContentTemplate>`.

Comment: @mdesdev I posted the rest of the code. And I didn't touched the fiddle code. The confusion is that why it is working fine in IE?

Comment: @MightyLampshade: Please look at my updated code.

Comment: Ok, try `<table style="position: relative; width: 100%; z-index: 9999;">`.

Comment: @mdesdev: didn't work :(

Comment: Sorry can't help you more...but it's CSS problem, probably some content overlapping other, you could try to put border on everything to see if something is overlapping `* { border: 1px dotted red; }` or just look properties in CSS for `#PopupMenu`, `#UpdatePanel2` and `.login_p` maybe some of them have big `height` and overlapping on ContentTemplate.